# Existence and uniqueness of IVP solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

Consider the IVP 
$$
y'=x\ln y, \quad y(1)=1
$$
The function $f(x,y)=x\ln y \,$ is continuous for $y>0$, so there exists a solution in some rectangle 
$$
R=\Big\{(x,y):|x-1|\leq a, |y-1|\leq b<1\Big\}$$

To show the uniqueness of this solution we take
$$
f_y=\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial y}=\frac{x}{y}
$$
which is continuous in $\mathbb{R^2}\setminus \big\{\ (x,y): y=0 \big\}$.

Can we thus conclude that the IVP has a unique solution in some rectangle
$$
R=\Big\{(x,y):|x-1|\leq a, |y-1|\leq b<1\Big\}$$

?

Comment: This looks like IVP to me

Comment: You're correct, I edited it.